# Error: PyDictionary would not install on Python 3.10.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, pydictionary

I use pycharm ide for coding, But when I tried installing PyDictionary module it gave this error on console:

[image: PyCharm screenshot]

The system is running windows10 with Python version 3.10.2 with latest pip and setuptool. All necessary path variables are set and other modules import and install without issues. This case is happening only with python 3.10.2

```
Collecting PyDictionary
  Using cached PyDictionary-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting goslate
  Using cached goslate-1.5.2.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting bs4
  Using cached bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting click
  Using cached click-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\sysadmin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from PyDictionary) (2.27.1)
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting colorama
  Using cached colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting futures
  Using cached futures-3.0.5.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [27 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 244, in <module>
      monkey.patch_all()
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
      patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 169, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
      patch_func(*msvc14('_get_vc_env'))
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
      mod = import_module(mod_name)
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 20, in <module>
      import unittest.mock
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 26, in <module>
      import asyncio
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      from .base_events import *
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
      import concurrent.futures
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ucxsouan\futures_c24a44afb56f439e8f819b7a8a5ff59d\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
    File "C:\Users\sysadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ucxsouan\futures_c24a44afb56f439e8f819b7a8a5ff59d\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 357
      raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                                 ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried the same on windows command shell with admin privileges. But same. Anyone has the same issue?

Comment: "I tried the same on windows command shell with admin privileges"—please _don't do this_. Only run things with elevated privileges if there is a reason to do so and you fully understand the implications. Blindly re-running failing commands as Administrator or root is a great way to break your system.

Comment: That error shows a Python 2-style `raise`. It looks like there's a transitive dependency on [`futures`](https://pypi.org/project/futures/), which explicitly does _not_ support Python 3: "It **does not** work on Python 3 due to Python 2 syntax being used in the codebase. Python 3 users should not attempt to install it, since the package is already included in the standard library."

Comment: 'But when I tried installing a module' *which* module?

Comment: @Sören sorry I forgot to mention PyDictionary.

Comment: @Chris you said PyDictionary is already included? How do you import and access it.

Comment: @dilersingh, no _PyDictionary_ is not included. [`concurrent.futures` is](https://docs.python.org/library/concurrent.futures.html). It looks like some nested dependency is trying to install the `futures` module from PyPI, which is a version backported to Python 2.

Comment: pydictionary depends on goslate, which depends on futures. This is a bug.

Comment: And [goslate itself appears to be deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/goslate/): "Google has updated its translation service recently with a ticket mechanism to prevent simple crawler program like `goslate` from accessing. Though a more sophisticated crawler may still work technically, however it would have crossed the fine line between using the service and breaking the service. `goslate` will not be updated to break google’s ticket mechanism. Free lunch is over. Thanks for using." So it's unlikely the author will invest any time fixing that bug.

Comment: @Sören so this translates to anyone using 3.10.2 not able to use PyDictionary. Awesome!!!

Comment: PyDictionary should probably just remove its dependency on `goslate`. There is [an open issue for this](https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary/issues/42).

Comment: @dilersingh, likely any version of Python 3, not just the latest. And to be clear: this is something that the PyDictionary folks should fix. It's _their_ fault, not Python's or PyCharm's or anybody else's. They are the ones depending on an old, unmaintained library that is itself buggy. Feel free to add your voice to that open issue.

Comment: `goslate`'s source repository appears to have been removed: https://bitbucket.org/zhuoqiang/goslate

Comment: @Chris https://github.com/zhuoqiang/goslate

Comment: @Sören, interesting. The contribution links still go to Bitbucket: https://github.com/zhuoqiang/goslate#how-to-contribute In any case, that doesn't change much. goslate is deprecated and broken; PyDictionary should probably stop depending on it.

Answer (score 6):

PyDictionary depends on **goslate** which is dependant on **futures**, since futures is not supported by **Python 3** it causes error.
One way of preventing this is to install **goslate** directly from the GitHub Repository, here is the [link](https://github.com/yeahwhat-mc/goslate). But you will not get the latest version.

First install **goslate** from GitHub Repository:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/yeahwhat-mc/goslate#egg=goslate
```

Then install **PyDictionary**:

```
pip install PyDictionary
```

Comment: works for python 3.11 thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For me upgrading `setuptools` solved it.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Answer (score 1):

Try going with wordhoard or py-dictionary

```
pip install wordhoard
pip install Py-Dictionary
```

and you can perform the operations. Below I have found the synonym of the word

```
inp_word = "name"
dict = Dictionary(inp_word,50)
#Py-dictionary
for i in dict.synonyms():
    syn_words.append(i)

#wordhoard
for i in Synonyms(inp_word).find_synonyms():
    syn_words.append(i)

print(set(syn_words))
```

Mostly both will have same results but I don't want to leave out things so only I am using combinedly